# Access nameless objects in a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, rgb

I have the following list:

```
var colorsList = [
  { nome: 'vermelho', rgb: [255, 0, 0] },
  { nome: 'verde', rgb: [0, 255, 0] },
  { nome: 'azul', rgb: [0, 0, 255] }
];
```

I'm trying to access the RGB values of "vermelho" (red). How can I do it?
I tried `colorsList.rgb[0]` but this isn't it.

Comment: `colorsList[0].rgb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy that you want the first item in the list

```
colorsList[0].rgb
```

If you want to lookup the item by name

```
colorsList.find(x => x.nome === "vermelho").rgb
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfecly. By the way, you made a little typo: it's colorsList, not colorList

Answer (score 1):

use `colorsList[0].rgb[0]` or `colorsList.find(color => color.nome === 'vermelho').rgb[0]`